# How to fix 'The captcha you entered is incorrect.' error in Recaptcha v3

Tags: php, html, bigcommerce, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to configure/update ReCaptcha from v2 to v3.

I have changed the code and in the bottom right corner I can see that Recaptcha v3 is working.

[image]

BUT..

After filling the fields and pressing the button 'Submit' the error message appears saying that "The captcha you entered is incorrect. Please try again."

What could be causing the issue?

This is the script:

```
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=MY_SITE_KEY"></script>
    <script>
        grecaptcha.ready(function () {
            grecaptcha.execute('MY_SITE_KEY', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {
                var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
                recaptchaResponse.value = token;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you change 'MY_SITE_KEY' to the key issued to you by Google?

Comment: Yes, I did, @DaveS.

Comment: is this on a blueprint store?

Comment: @aisflat439 It's a bigcommerce store.

Comment: It's a stencil theme